# 10k Tenants and Multi-Tenant DB Design

Tags: sql-server, database

We are trying to decide on a database design for a new web application.  We expect to have close to 10,000 tenants and would like to keep their data in separate databases if it makes sense to do so.  Each tenant will have a DB that is around 20MB they are tracking mostly the personal data of 50 to 100 youth and 100 to 300 adults plus events, attendance, awards etc.  I do not know how many total users would log in at once but each tenant could have several.

My options as I understand them is to have:

- A shared-nothing approach giving each tenant a separate database.
- A schema approach giving each tenant separate tables.
- A shared-everything approach where each tenant has their own tenantID

I would ideally like the shared-nothing approach but I am unclear of how many databases you can have in SQL Server before you run into performance issues.  Managing multiple databases is not a major concern for us but if SQL Server becomes unresponsive due to the number of DBs this is the kind of information I am seeking.  Keep in mind the databases are small 20MB on average.

Performance wise which approach would be the best route for us to take?  Please also take into consideration of having multiple SQL Server Licenses would not be ideal cost wise.  But if it is necessary please let me know.

I have also read several post here and also [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) but I haven't seen a real clear winner with a large number of tenants but really small databases.

Also which version of SQL Server would be ideal?

If anyone has experience with something similar please let me know how you handled this and if it is working out well.  Any real world experience/advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Your predicted database size is only a 1/4 gig, not very big.  I'd say use #3, "A shared-everything approach where each tenant has their own tenantID" so you keep management easy.

Comment: If you are writing your code tightly and you assign each tenant their own ID you are better off. Just make sure everytime you make a db call require a tenantID.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms143432.aspx, the maximum number of db's allowed is 32,767.

Comment: I also saw that the max number is 32,767 but I have read several post that you shouldn't be going anywhere near that number and you could have performance issues with as little as 1000 to 2000 Databases.  But I don't know how this relates to having really small databases nor any real world data to back this up.  One of our requirements is to be able to restore a tenants data from a backup and this would be so much easier if the separate database approach would work.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of a opinion question because there really is no right answer. All 3 would work in your situation. Here are some things to think about:

**Why does it have to be in separate databases?**: If they have to do it because they have direct access to the database then of course by all means you have to do this. It sounds thought like the users will have some sort of an application they are using so this wouldn't be the best solution? The other thing that would make this a better option is if its possible the tenant may be moved to a separate server later on. Example: ABC_Widgets might host the data on their own server at some point in time. Right now they are being hosted together with all the other tenants.

**Each db will have its own overhead**  Albeit small, remember SQL will allocate some space for each db. Now multiply that by 10,000 DB's and you have a chunk of wasted space.

**Connection Strings** From a development standpoint, when you connect to the database you will either have to have multiple connection strings or a dynamically created connection string based on the database being used.

**The Schema Approach** I think the best use case for this is, for example Tenant A is not going to be having the same tables and Tenant G or Tenant F might need a specialized table/schema for a custom situation.

IMHO I think you would be best using the assign a `tenantID` to each tenant and store it in 1 database.