# MySQL Multi Tenant Application - Too Many Tables & Performance Issues

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi-tenant application where for each tenant I create separate set of 50 tables in a single MySQL database in LAMP environment.

In each set average table size is 10 MB with the exception of about 10 tables having size between 50 to 200MB.

MySQL InnoDB creates 2 files(.frm & .ibd) for each table.

For 100 tenants there will be 100 x 50 = 5000 Tables x 2 Files = 10,000 Files

It looks too high to me. Am I doing it in a wrong way or its common in this kind of scenario. What other options I should consider ?

I also [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311118/10k-tenants-and-multi-tenant-db-design) but this question was closed by moderators so it did not attract many thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have one *database* per tenant.  That would be 100 directories, each with 2*50 = 100 files.  100 is reasonable; 10,000 items in a directory is dangerously high in most operating systems.

**Addenda**

If you have 15 tables that are used by all tenants, put them in one extra database.  If you call that db `Common`, then consider these snippits:

```
USE Tenant;    -- Customer starts in his own db
SELECT ... FROM table1 ...;   -- Accesses `table1` for that tenant
SELECT a.this, b.blah
    FROM table1 AS a             -- tenant's table
    JOIN Common.foo AS b  ON ... -- common table
```

Note on grants...

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Tenant_123.* TO tenant_123@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ...;
GRANT SELECT ON Common.* TO tenant_123@'%';
```

That is, it is probably OK to 'grant' everything to his own database.  *But* he show have very limited access to the `Common` data.

If, instead, you manage the logins and all accesses go through, say, a PHP API, then you probably have only one mysql 'user' for all accesses.  In this case, my notes above about `GRANTs` are not relevant.

Do *not* let the Tenants have access to everything.  Your entire system will quickly be hacked and possibly destroyed.

Comment: If MySQL has to manage multiple databases as compared to one database then will it add additional overheads? Also there are some 15 common tables  shared by all tenants so overall no of files will also increase if we have separate database for each tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this has little to do with which way to do it versus which way you've basically sold your customers on how it's to be done, or in some cases having no choice due to the type of data.

For example, does your application have a policy or similar that defines isolation of user generated data? Does your application store HIPAA or PCI type data? If so, you may not even have a choice, and if the customer is expecting that sort of privacy, that normally comes at a premium due to the potential overhead of creating the separation.

If the separation/isolation of data is not required, then adding a field to tables indicating which application owns the data would be most ideal from a performance perspective, and you would just need to update your queries to filter based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL or MariaDB I prefer to use a single database for all tenants and restrict access to data by using a different database user per tenant which only has permission to their data.

You can accomplish by using an tenant_id column that stores the database username of the tenant that owns the data.  I use a trigger to populate this column automatically when new rows are added.  I then use Views to filter the tables where the tenant_id = current_database_user.  Then I restrict the tenant database users to only have access to the views, not the real tables.

I was able to convert a large single-tenant application to a multi-tenant application over a weekend using this technique because I only needed to modify the database and my database connection code.

I've written a blog post fully describing this approach.  https://opensource.io/it/mysql-multi-tenant/